# stalled migration from Google Work Space to MS 365 Business Std DNS servers

Tags: domain-name-system

I have inherited a small group that stalled moving from Google Work Space to MS 365 Bus std. DNS names 4  Host records pointing to Google Work Space. MS says the only thing i have left to do is change to the MS host servers.  The owner wants to keep his Work Space Gmail. Not sure what will happen to it when I change servers?  What can I do to make sure he continues to receive his personal Gmail via GWS.

Comment: It’s not really clear what you are asking. It’s not clear if you migrating email to O365, if you are changing your nameservers, etc. not enough info here to answer. Simply put if you change the DNS MX records all the mail is going to flow somewhere else. One person in the domain does not get to keep his email somewhere else. If you’re moving to O365 then perform a cutover migration and import all the Gmail in to O365. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/perform-g-suite-migration